# dismiss a modally presented view controller to a different underlying view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a UIViewController that's embedded in a Navigation View Controller. I then modally present another view controller that shows a countdown. Once the countdown ends, the modal view controller should be dismissed and show a different underlying view controller from the original presenting UIViewController.

Does anyone know how to do this in ios8 with Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to approach this.  One way is to replace the initial presenting view controller with the desired underlying one when you present the modal view controller.

```
NSArray * viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 1 withObject:replacementController];
```

Dismissing the modal will simply show the different underlying view controller that was already swapped.

Answer (score 0):

when you do `popViewController` from stack there is a handler. This will be called at the end of this function so you can pass a block where you can `presentViewController` or make change to the current one.